# ack does not find symlinks

Tags: symlink, ack

Here is a test:

```
$ ln -nfs ~/.ssh ssh  # Create a symlink in current dir.
$ ack -g ssh          # => nothing found
$ ack -a -g ssh       # => same here
$ find . -name ssh    # => found: ./ssh
```

What I am doing wrong? )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things are going against your expectations.

First, ack will ignore symlinks if you don't use the `--follow` switch.

Second, and more importantly, `ack -g` does not find directories.  It only finds files.  ack is a file-based utility.  It is not a generic utility like `find` is.

Comment: My expectation was based on fact, that symlink is a special kind of file and if I do not use the `--follow` key why I cannot find it?

Comment: Because your symlink stands for a directory, so ack doesn't consider it to be a file.  Basically, `-f` and `-g` are for "files that ack would have searched inside of".